# Should steps in a wizard display in breadcrumbs?

Tags: wizard, breadcrumbs

The application I'm working on displays historical breadcrumbs. There's one section of the app that utilizes a wizard. Should the steps in the wizard also be displayed in the breadcrumbs, or just the page the wizard lives in?

Here's a screenshot that does not include the wizard steps in the breadcrumb.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

welcome. Breadcrumbs are a [wayfinding tool](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/breadcrumbs/) that help users understand where they can go on a site. Showing steps both in a stepper and in the breadcrumb might cause user confusion ("What's the difference between these two?"), so use your breadcrumb to show where the page is in the site hierarchy, and the stepper for links to steps.

Comment: I would also add numbers to the steps 1. Contact, 2. Select, etc. This'll help separate the action steps from navigation breadcrumbs.

Comment: Thanks! I originally included numbers in the steps, but then the directive was to remove them, because the user doesn't necessarily have to go through the steps from start to finish, and can leave and save after only the first step if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no need to display  breadcrumbs in each and every step. You can have a breadcrumb for the step page and underneath the step you can have a step description.

[image]

Let page wizard lives in. Because there is no back if use steps for the breadcrumb.